# Is there a way to check if an email is listed in PayPal's transactions tab?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've tried looking it up everywhere, but I wasn't able to find anything. Checked PayPal's developer subdomain, still no luck. Is there even a way to do that? If so how can I use it, to check an email? Let's say, I have a buyer, whos email is "mike@example.com" and I want to check if he actually paid, via javascript.

**I'm specifically looking for a docs page**, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there must be. With the paypal API there is like a module called identity [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/) look for the first sample result.

Comment: Thanks for linking me it, I really appreciate it.